# how to check whether file exists or not using content uri

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, nativescript

I have a content uri of an audio file, which I got it from chooser intent.

```
content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/KannadaGeeta/11CHAPTER10.mp3
```

I just saved the above uri on database.

Now, when user opens my app again. I need to inform him whether the last mp3 file which he selected exists or not. If exists then only I must allow him to continue else I need to inform to download the file again.

but I stuck here completely, I'm not getting how to check a file exist or not with its content uri.

Kindly, help me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 :-**
Ok, Since Android team decided to deprecate `getExternalStorageDirectory` for security reason. Lot of things are not properly addressed by them.

for the question I don't find any proper answer. Anyhow here is a workaround by using deprecated method.

```
        var uri = Uri.parse("content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/KannadaGeeta/11CHAPTER10.mp3")
        var vidPath = uri.path
        vidPath = vidPath?.replace("external_files",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())
        val file = File(vidPath)

        if (file.exists()) {
            println("log yes $file")
        } else {
            println("log no $file")
        }
```

This will work fine, but using this is left to you because of deprecated method.

**Method 2 :-**
one more way is to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`
then in `onActivityResult` it must add

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or       
                     Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(selectedVideoUri!!, takeFlags)
```

Then, finally with the `content uri` which is not expired, one can check for file existance.

```
DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(Uri.parse(contentUriStringfromdatabase)).exists()
```

Answer (score -5):

```
 File file = new File(URI.create("your uri").getPath());
 if (file.exists()) {
  //Do something`enter code here`
 }
```

Also you need the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: this will not working. because when I print the `file` i'll  get `/external_files/KannadaGeeta/11CHAPTER10.mp3`. which always return false.

Comment: try to replace content: with file:

Comment: i didn't understood, what are you saying. give example.